# Website shows raw code before rendering HTML contents

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

My PHP mysql driven website shows a bunch of raw code for about half a second before rendering the website. I have added more mysql queries recently which run before the entire page is generated, but removing them makes no difference. It only comes up after the login process, then when I refresh or even when the browser cache is cleared, but when I logout, it shows again. But: the code only shows under Chrome, not when using the Firefox browser. This only started to occur last week.

What is the reason for this, and how can this be prevented?

Below is the initial Javascript code that recognizes the screen resolution in order to later adjust the dimensions of different HTML elements (it checks if the resolution is already recognised through a GET variable, if not, then the same page is reloaded once). When I remove this code and have the page directly go to the PHP, the raw code does not show. I believe the raw code that shows up is this Javascript. But this problem did not occur before, this website has operated in this fashion with this code for over a year!

```
    $adj = 0;
if (isset($_GET['adj'])) $adj = intval($_GET['adj']); // Anpassung an Browserfensteraufloesung 

if (empty($adj)) { 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 

<script language="javascript">
    // Browserfensteraufloesung wird erkannt

    if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
        //Non-IE
        browser_width = window.innerWidth;
        browser_height = window.innerHeight;
    } else if ( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
        //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
        browser_width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        browser_height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
        //IE 4 compatible
        browser_width = document.body.clientWidth;
        browser_height = document.body.clientHeight;
    }


    var browser_width_previous = "<? echo $screen_width ?>";
    var browser_height_previous = "<? echo $screen_height ?>";

    if (browser_width != browser_width_previous || browser_height != browser_height_previous) {

        var datum = "<? echo $datum_range ?>";
        var datum_von = "<? echo $datum_von ?>";
        var datum_bis = "<? echo $datum_bis ?>";
        var dateiname = "<? echo $search_dateiname ?>";
        var dateiname_default = "<? echo $search_dateiname_default ?>";
        if (dateiname == dateiname_default) dateiname = ""; // Notwendig, damit nicht nach diesem Defaultwert gesucht wird
        var status = "<? echo $encoding_status ?>";
        var kdnr_search_strg = "";
        var kd_nr = "<? echo $kunden_nummer ?>";

        if (kd_nr == "<? echo $admin_kd_nr; ?>") 
                kdnr_search_strg = "&Kd_nr_search=" + "<? echo $kd_nr_search ?>";

        new_location = "kundendaten_viewer.php?Datum_range=" + datum + "&Datum_von=" + datum_von + "&Datum_bis=" + datum_bis + "&BrowserWinWidth=" + browser_width + "&BrowserWinHeight=" + browser_height + "&Search_dateiname=" + dateiname + "&Encoding_status=" + status + kdnr_search_strg + "&adj=1";
        //alert (' Location: ' + new_location);
    window.location = new_location;//"kundendaten_viewer_debug.php?BrowserWinWidth=" + browser_width + "&BrowserWinHeight=" + browser_height + "&Datum_range=" + datum + "&Search_dateiname=" + dateiname + "&Encoding_status=" + status + kdnr_search_strg + "&adj=1"; 
    } //else alert (browser_width + " = " + browser_width_previous);
    </script>

<?php
}
```

Comment: Are you declaring your CSS file outside of your head tag by any chance? Also, as a point of interest, this is occasionally happening to me on Facebook with Chrome too.

Comment: Have you got some sample code? We cannot guess what your website and code is like.

Comment: If you can put an example of the code on one of your pages here we can help you further.

Comment: The raw code that shows up is an initial Javascript bit that gets screen resolution and adjusts the window size accordingly. After that comes lots of PHP which is fed with mysql data and forms divs and a table. The page has always needed to load a bit before it showed up and rendered the table, but it never showed the raw code while doing so. CSS files are all declared within the head tag. The code is very long which makes it hard to decide what sample code to give you.

Comment: Sample code has been posted now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a header.php, where you initiate the html to the start of the body tag and add the css files to the html there. In the other php files you just have to use `include_once 'header.php';` and this way your css is included earlier, than your query runs. I hope this will solve your problem. NOTE: if you use sessions, `session_start()` must be the first row because sessions can't be started after any headers sent.

Comment: This is a very good beginner suggestion, but now how things are done in the professional world. You should use a template engine rather than php headers.

Comment: Unfortunately this has not helped.

Comment: @STT LCU Yeah, you can use smarty or whatever engine you can work with, but as I see, he doesn't use any engine or framework or cms.

Comment: because probably he doesn't even know the existence of such tools. That's why I mentioned them in the comment. There's nothing bad per se in your answer.